# Why does my setInterval seem to run one last time after an alert message?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a simple n-back game, and at the end of a session I have an alert message popping up to tell the user their n-back level is being increased if they score 75% or better. For some reason though, after the user clicks OK or hits enter, the `setInterval` function seems to be running through one more time. On the grid I have created, one more square lights up, even though the session is supposed to be over. I will post the relevant game code below:

```
$('#start').click(function()
  {
    let counter = 0;
    message_switch = true;
    $('#start').blur();
    $('#score-output').text(0);
    $('#percentage').text('%');
    var intervalID = setInterval(function()
      {
        counter++;
        show_card(get_cardID(cardIDs));
        if (counter === 30)
          {
            window.clearInterval(intervalID);
            message_switch = false;
            var score = Math.round((playerMatches.length / matches.length) * 100);
            score = score - (error_count * 3);
            update_score(score);
            if (score < 50)
              {
                if (n_back < 2)
                  {
                    n_back = 1;
                  } else {
                    n_back = n_back - 1;
                  }
              } else if (score < 75 && score >= 50)
                {
                  n_back = n_back;
                } else if (score >= 75) {
                  n_back = n_back + 1;
                };
            $('#nback').text(n_back);
            reset_game_values();
            if (score >= 75) //here there is some issue 
              {
                window.alert("Congratulations, you will move up to " + n_back + " back.");
                score = 0;
                return;
              } else {
                score = 0;
              }
          }
      }, 3500);
  })
```

I know this is a lot of code and there is also a lot of code I haven't provided, mainly just in an attempt to be brief. Does anyone see anything obvious that I am not seeing? If you feel you need to see more of the program I can provide it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're not clicking `#start` again in your process ?

Comment: I wondered that too, but the whole game session does not start over again. One grid card lights up one last time, and then the game ends, even though the game is already supposed to have ended since this method is used after the interval id has been used.

Comment: Make a repeatable example in snippet or jsfiddle, it does't seem to have problem with this code, the problem may come from html.

Comment: I tried to use codepen but for some reason it doesn't work at all in codepen. The code is the exact same, I just copied and pasted. This is over my head.

Comment: Will be hard to guess without having some snippet code to play. So i give you a few recommendations: **1)** Define the intervalID with gobal scope, that is, outside the listener for click event. **2)** Before starting a new `setInterval()` call `clearInterval(invervalID)`.

Comment: Does the second alert appear immediately after the first closes or is there a delay?